I want to turn this command into an alias with stdin, is there a way to?
In the command below, I want to be able to make the regex pattern in the perl process an stdin instead, and turn that into an alias, and maybe the filename at
the end to, I use this line a lot to find values in header files, and figured that it would be easier to turn it into an alias, and ideas?
sudo find /usr -type f | xargs perl -ne 'print "( $ARGV ) Line $.: $_" if $_ =~ /(#define\s*METHOD_NEITHER)/' 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | xargs -0 echo >> IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT_Values.txt &


Use a function, not an alias.

What do you mean by "make it an stdin instead"? stdin is the input stream of data. Did you mean a command-line argument? Aliases can't process arguments, but functions can.
